# How to create a Levey-Jenning plot with VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a levey-jenning plot with a macro in excel. So I am trying to write in VBA to get it so I have a scatterplot with two lines in it, the mean-2.5*std (lower limit) and mean+2.5*std (upper limit). and between those the data points. However, The lines don't range across the whole scatterplot. See picture. [image: Resulting scatterplot].

The scatterplot is created from the following table. [image: Table from which scatterplot is created]

The following VBA code is what I have created to make the plot.

```
Sub CreateLeveyJenningsPlotWithSelection()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim chartRange As Range
    Dim chartObject As chartObject
    Dim chartTitle As String
    Dim userInput1 As String
    Dim userInput2 As String
    Dim minDate As Date
    Dim maxDate As Date
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad1")
    
    ' Ask the user for row selection (e.g., "2:20")
    userInput1 = InputBox("Enter the first column index after header(e.g., 3)")
    userInput2 = InputBox("Enter the index number after the last column index.")
    
    ' Validate user input (optional)
    If Not IsNumeric(Left(userInput1, 1)) Or Not IsNumeric(Left(userInput2, 1)) Then
        MsgBox "Invalid input. Please enter valid row numbers."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set the data range based on user input (assuming column E)
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("F" & userInput1 & ":F" & userInput2)
    
    ' Calculate mean and standard deviation
    Dim meanMFI As Double
    Dim stdevMFI As Double
    meanMFI = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataRange)
    stdevMFI = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(dataRange)
    
    ' Set control limits (e.g., 2 standard deviations)
    Dim upperLimit As Double
    Dim lowerLimit As Double
    upperLimit = meanMFI + 2.5 * stdevMFI
    lowerLimit = meanMFI - 2.5 * stdevMFI
    
    ' Set x-axis limits based on date data
    minDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Range("C2:C" & userInput2))
    maxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("C2:C" & userInput2))
    
    ' Create a scatter plot
    Set chartObject = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
    
    ' Set the chart range (exclude header row)
    Set chartRange = dataRange.Resize(dataRange.Rows.Count - 1, dataRange.Columns.Count)
    
    With chartObject.Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SetSourceData Source:=chartRange
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.Text = "Levey-Jennings Plot"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Date"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "MFI Value"
        
        ' Add upper limit line
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Upper Control Limit"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Array(upperLimit, upperLimit)
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array(minDate, maxDate)
        .SeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
        
        ' Add lower limit line
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Lower Control Limit"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Array(lowerLimit, lowerLimit)
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Array(minDate, maxDate)
        .SeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
        .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red color
        
                
        ' Add data points
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "Actual Data Points"
        .SeriesCollection(3).Values = dataRange
        .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = dataRange
        .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Array(minDate, maxDate)
        .SeriesCollection(3).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        .SeriesCollection(3).MarkerSize = 5
        .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.Visible = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I have tried to add the dates as x-axis values with the upper and lower limit to fix the fact that the lines don't cross the whole scatterplot. `.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array(minDate, maxDate)`. But as you can see in the scatterplot, this does not fix anything. I am stuck here.

I would like help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out (simplified a little from your setup) :

**EDIT** - added code to plot only visible vales

```
Sub CreateLeveyJenningsPlotWithSelection()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lo As ListObject
    Dim meanMFI As Double, stdevMFI As Double
    Dim upperLimit As Double, lowerLimit As Double
    Dim co As Shape, cht As Chart
    Dim dataRange As Range, datesRange As Range
    Dim minDate, maxDate, dateVals, dataVals
    
    ' Set the worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1)
    
    ws.Shapes(1).Delete
    
    dataVals = VisibleDataToArray(lo.ListColumns("MFI").DataBodyRange)
    dateVals = VisibleDataToArray(lo.ListColumns("Date").DataBodyRange)
    dateVals = ToNumber(dateVals) 'coerce to numeric not date for plotting
    
    ' Calculate mean, standard deviation and limits
    meanMFI = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(dataVals)
    stdevMFI = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(dataVals)
    upperLimit = meanMFI + 2.5 * stdevMFI
    lowerLimit = meanMFI - 2.5 * stdevMFI
    
    ' Set x-axis limits based on date data
    minDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(dateVals)
    maxDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dateVals)
    
    ' Create a scatter plot
    Set co = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlXYScatter, Left:=200, _
                                Width:=375, Top:=50, Height:=225)
    Set cht = co.Chart
    Do While cht.SeriesCollection.Count > 0 'clear any "autoplotted" series
        cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Loop
    
    'format chart
    With cht
        .HasTitle = True
        .chartTitle.Text = "Levey-Jennings Plot"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Date"
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "MFI Value"
    End With
    
    'add data points
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Actual Data Points"
        .XValues = dateVals
        .Values = dataVals
        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        .MarkerSize = 5
        .Format.line.Visible = False
    End With
    
    'add control lines
    ControlLine cht, "Upper Control Limit", Array(minDate, maxDate), _
                Array(upperLimit, upperLimit), vbRed

    ControlLine cht, "Lower Control Limit", Array(minDate, maxDate), _
                Array(lowerLimit, lowerLimit), vbRed

End Sub

'add a control ine using the supplied parameters
Sub ControlLine(cht As Chart, nm As String, xvals, yvals, clr As Long)
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = nm
        .Values = yvals
        .XValues = xvals
        .MarkerStyle = -4142
        .Format.line.Visible = True
        .Format.line.Weight = 0.75
        .Format.line.ForeColor.RGB = vbRed
    End With
End Sub

'return a zero-based array of values from visible cells
'  in the single-column range `rng`
Function VisibleDataToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim arr, c As Range, n As Long, rngVis As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVis = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then
        n = 0
        ReDim arr(0 To rngVis.Cells.Count - 1)
        For Each c In rngVis.Cells
            arr(n) = c.Value
            n = n + 1
        Next c
        VisibleDataToArray = arr
    End If
End Function

'return an array of numbers (in this case from an array of dates)
Function ToNumber(ByVal arrIn)
    Dim i As Long, arr
    ReDim arr(0 To UBound(arrIn))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn)
        arr(i) = arrIn(i) * 1
    Next i
    ToNumber = arr
End Function
```

Data and chart:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have it select a column index range via user input as to select certain subsets?

Comment: Yes - as you had in your original post

Comment: I got it to work thanks to you, I however also wonder if it is possible to exclude hidden rows from the arrays.

I now have Arrays with the necessary elements in them. But it also includes rows that are hidden, I.e. that should be excluded from the subsets.


How can I create an array for both the MFImean, MFIstdev and datesRange that excludes hidden rows? I tried to create a for loop that should do this but constantly get errors.

Comment: I had to add a - 1 after userInput1  so that the first index of the rows was included. But It works perfectly with the suggestions of Tim Williams.